# Playwright webkit is not working on Windows 10

Tags: webkit, playwright

I'm trying to write a simple e2e test.

```
import {chromium, webkit, firefox} from "playwright";

(async () => {
    for (const browserType of [chromium, firefox, webkit]) {
        const browser = await browserType.launch({ headless: false });
        const context = await browser.newContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();

        await page.goto("https://github.com");
        await page.fill('input[aria-label="Search GitHub"]', "Playwright");
        await page.press('input[aria-label="Search GitHub"]', "Enter");

        await page.click(".repo-list-item:nth-child(1) a");
        await page.click('span[data-content="Security"]');
        await page.screenshot({path: `screenshots/security-${browserType.name()}.png`, fullPage: false});

        await page.close();
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

This code is working fine with chromium and firefox. However, when I use webkit it breaks on [the second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iInv4.png).
Webkit error logs:

```
 Error.captureStackTrace(stackObject);
             ^
page.click: Protocol error (Runtime.awaitPromise): The page has been closed.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector ".repo-list-item:nth-child(1) a"
  selector resolved to visible <a class="v-align-middle" href="/microsoft/playwrig…>…</a>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and not moving
    element is moving - waiting...
  element is visible, enabled and does not move
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  checking that element receives pointer events at (468,222)
  <div class="mr-3">↵            Apache-2.0 license↵          </div> from <div>…</div> subtree intercepts pointer events
retrying click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and not moving
    element is moving - waiting...
  element is visible, enabled and does not move
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  checking that element receives pointer events at (468,222)
  <div class="mr-3">↵            Apache-2.0 license↵          </div> from <div>…</div> subtree intercepts pointer events
retrying click action
```

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Your code is working for me. Are you running Playwright 1.4?

Comment: Yes, I am running Playwright 1.4.

Comment: what is your Node.Js version? For me it works on Win10 with Node v12.16.1 and Playwright 1.4. It may worth a clean install of the node_modules (after deleting the lock file as well).

Comment: My Node.Js version is 12.14.1. I tried to clean install the node_modules and nothing has changed. I updated Node.js version, now i'm on 14.10.1, clean installed the node_modules and the problem is still there.

Comment: I tried to install Node v12.16.1, but it has no effect.